# perform numerical operation over each element in data frame based on corresponding elements in another data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame created with columns names ['0','1','2','3']. The elements of this data frame are numerical values . Let's call it 'df_1'

Now I need to create another data frame (say df_2) with same index and column name as df_1.

The elements df_2 are such that:

1. Whenever the column name is '0', all rows under it will be marked as 0.
2. For any other column in df_2, it's row element would be the sum of corresponding row element in df_1 and the row element present under the column just before the current column

i.e

> df_2[i,j]=df_1[i,j]+df_1[i,j-1], whenever current column name is not '0'
>
> df_2[i,j]=  0 , whenever current column name is '0'

I have written a python code for this operation and it is working fine . But the method adopted is not efficient and very convoluted.

Please let me know if there is a better way to perform the same

```py
import pandas
df_1=pandas.DataFrame([[0,10,20,30],[0,40,50,60],[0,70,80,90]],columns=['0','1','2','3'])

df_2=pandas.DataFrame(0,index=df_1.index,columns=df_1.columns)

for j in list(df_1.columns):
    idx=list(df_1.columns).index(j)
    for i in range(len(df_1.index)):
        if j!='0':
            df_2.iloc[i,idx]=df_1.iloc[i,idx-1]+df_1.iloc[i,idx]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First shift your columns one to the right and then add to the original columns, make this equal to df_2.

```
df_2 = df_1 + df_1.shift(1, axis=1)
```

Filter columns for column '0' and then make equal ot 0.

```
df_2['0'] = 0
```

Pandas will convert to float during this operation, convert back to int if you wish.

```
df_2.astype('int32')
```